# How to filter pandas DataFrame based on SQL conditions in Python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, filter

I would like to convert my SQL code into a Python (pandas) filter function, but it is giving me a hard time. Any idea how I can filter my data based on the SQL conditions without looping through the records? The `Value` check for `Desc` = 'Bla1' makes the difference.

> if `joe_doe`: keep records with `Hello` = 1; else: keep records with
>   `Hello` = 0

**SQL**

```
Hello =
        CASE
            WHEN
            (
                Desc = 'Bla1'
                AND Value = 'True'
            )
            OR
            (
                Desc IN('Bla2', 'Bla3')
                AND Active = 'True'                 
            )
            AND Enabled = 'True'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
```

**Python (incl. pandas)**

```
def get_it(john_doe, df):

    sentences = {
            'Bla1': 'Value',
            'Bla2': 'Active',
            'Bla3': 'Active'
        }

    if john_doe:
        df = df[HOW TO KEEP ALL RECORDS THAT HAVE Hello = 1?]
    else:
        df = df[HOW TO KEEP ALL RECORDS THAT HAVE Hello = 0?]
    return df
```

**DataFrame input**

```
id | Desc | Active | Enabled | Value | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
1  | Bla2 | 1      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla3 | 1      | 1       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
3  | Bla3 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] 
4  | Bla4 | 1      | 1       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
5  | Bla6 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
6  | Bla7 | 0      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
7  | Bla1 | 0      | 1       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
8  | Bla1 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
```

**DataFrame needed ouput for IF JOE_DOE**

```
id | Desc | Active | Enabled | Value | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla3 | 1      | 1       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
3  | Bla3 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
7  | Bla1 | 0      | 1       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
```

**DataFrame needed ouput for ELSE**

```
id | Desc | Active | Enabled | Value | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
1  | Bla2 | 1      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
4  | Bla4 | 1      | 1       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
5  | Bla6 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
6  | Bla7 | 0      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
8  | Bla1 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
```

Comment: this question is confusing - can you please include a sample of your df? are you trying to mimic the case statement, or do you just need to know what to put in the if statement?

Comment: I would like to filter my `df` based on the SQL conditions in Python/pandas.In `if` I would like to keep all records according the conditions in SQL (`THEN 1`). In `else` I would like to keep all records that are not following the conditions in SQL (`ELSE 0`)

Comment: The `sentences` dict contains all SQL cases, because `Bla1` checks for the `Value` field. The other 2 check for the `Active` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Pandas can take any number of logical arguments to filter a dataframe. `&` and `|` are used to separate arguments, and `~` is used to negate an argument. I don't understand the need for the `dict` you built, and I don't think it's necessary in this case.

```
logic1 = (df.Desc=='Bla11') & (df.Value==1) & (df.Enabled==1)
logic2 = (df.Desc=='Bla12') & (df.Active==1) & (df.Enabled==1)
logic3 = (df.Desc=='Bla13') & (df.Active==1) & (df.Enabled==1)

if joe_doe:
     df = df[logic1 | logic2 | logic3]
else:
     df = df[~logic1 & ~logic2 & ~logic3]
return df
```